# The Pig Dice Game Human vs Computer Java Program

Tags: java

I have been working on this program for about a week now and I think I have it down pack. The issue I am having when I ask the user at the beginning of the game (human vs computer) every time I run the program it asks me what my name is again. Here is what I have thus far:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;  

 public class Assignment  
 {  
 Scanner usersName;  
 Boolean humanTurn = true;  
 Boolean computerTurn = true;  
 int dice;  
 int humanTurnPoints, computerTurnPoints;  
 int humanTotalPoints = 0;
 int computerTotalPoints = 0;
 private Scanner keyboard;
 private Scanner key;   

 //System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
 //usersName = new Scanner(System.in);  
 //setStart(usersName.nextLine());

 public void roll()  
     {  
     dice = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;                   
     }      

 public int humanTurnScore()  
     {  
         {  
             humanTurnPoints = dice + humanTurnPoints;  
             System.out.println("You threw: " + dice);
             System.out.println("You have scored: " + humanTurnPoints + " in your turn.");  
         } return humanTurnPoints;  
     } 
 public void humanTurnZero()
 {
    humanTurnPoints = 0;
 } 

 public int computerTurnScore()  
     {  
         {  
             computerTurnPoints = dice + computerTurnPoints;  
             System.out.println("Computer has scored: " + computerTurnPoints + " in its turn.");  
         } return computerTurnPoints;  
     }     
  public void computerTurnZero()
     {
        computerTurnPoints = 0;
     } 

 public Assignment()  
 {  
     humanGame();  
     if(!humanTurn)  
     {  
         computerTurn();  
     }  
 }  
 public int humanGame()
    { 

     System.out.println("To start the game please press 'r'.");  
     key = new Scanner(System.in);  
     String start = key.nextLine();  
     if(!start.equalsIgnoreCase("R")) 
     {
            System.out.println("Make sure you are pressing 'r'.");
            humanGame();
     }

     if(start.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
        {                          
                     System.out.println("You pressed 'r'.");  
                     System.out.println("Lets start.");           


         do{  
             roll();    


             if(dice == 1)  
             {  
                 System.out.println("You got 1 and you lost your turn.");
                 System.out.println("Computer's GRAND TOTAL score is: " + computerTotalPoints);
                 humanTurnZero();            
                 computerTurn();  

             }  
             else if(dice != 1) 
             {

                 humanTotalPoints += dice;  
                    if(humanTotalPoints >= 100)    
                    {  
                        System.out.println("You threw: " + dice);
                        System.out.println("Your GRAND TOTAL score is: " + humanTotalPoints);
                        System.out.println("Congratulations, you win!");  
                        System.exit(0);  
                    } 
                 humanTurnScore();  
                 System.out.println("Your GRAND TOTAL score is: " + humanTotalPoints);  
                 System.out.println("Computer's GRAND TOTAL score is: " + computerTotalPoints);
                 System.out.println("You can hold or roll again.");  
                 System.out.println("To roll again press 'r' or 'h' to hold.");  
                 keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  
                 String choice = keyboard.nextLine();  

                 if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))                                  
                     {  
                       System.out.println("You pressed 'r'.");  
                       System.out.println("Lets roll again.");   
                       roll();           

                             if(!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
                                {
    System.out.println("You didn't press 'r'. To make sure the program is running correctly please press 'r' to roll or 'h' to hold.");
                                    humanGame();
                                }
                    }

                 if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))  
                     {                         
                     System.out.println("You pressed 'h' and loose your turn.");
                     System.out.println("Your Grand total is: " + humanTotalPoints);
                     humanTurnZero();  
                     computerTurn();  
                     }     

                }  

        }while(humanTurn);     

     }return dice;  
 }  
  public int computerTurn()  
  {  
 System.out.println("Now it's computer turn.");  

 do {  
     roll();  

     if(dice != 1)  
     {  
         computerTotalPoints += dice; 
            if(computerTotalPoints >=100)  
                {  
                    System.out.println("Computer threw: " + dice);
                    System.out.println("Computer's GRAND TOTAL score is: " +  computerTotalPoints);
                    System.out.println("Game Over! the computer wins");  
                    System.exit(0);  
                }   
         System.out.println("Computer threw: " + dice);
         System.out.println("Computer's GRAND TOTAL score is: " + computerTotalPoints);
         System.out.println("Your Grand total is: " + humanTotalPoints);
         computerTurnScore();  
         roll();  
     }  

     if(dice == 1)   
     {  
         System.out.println("Computer thrown 1 therefore it's your turn now.");  
         computerTurnZero();  
         humanGame();  
     }  

     if(computerTurnPoints >= 20)  
     {  
         System.out.println("Computer scored already " + computerTurnPoints + " you'd  better start to focus.");  
         System.out.println("Please play again");  
         humanGame();  
     }   

 }while (computerTurn);  
 return dice;  

 }     


 public static void main(String[] args)  
 {  
 new Assignment();  
 }  
 }
```

I commented out (up close to the top of the program) where I am asking the user at the beginning of the program what their name is. I actually need in all the System.out.println where it says 'You' I need it to say the usersName.

Would someone please help me with this program. I know someone is kind enough to help me out here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: distill your program down to the smallest example that will describe your problem and resubmit - 99.9% of the logic you've posted is irrelevant to the problem

Comment: Were you thinking that variables saved their values inside your program when you close it / restart it?

Comment: I would like to ask the user at the beginning of the program what their name is.  That is where I am have a problem.  I am unable reduce to the smallest code because I am relatively new at programming I am trying to get this to work. Thanks anyway.  Is there anyone else out there that would help me with this program?

Answer (score 2):

Of course it will ask you that every time!
You need to save this in a file, and then read from it!

```
    //Write
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");
    writer.println(usersName.nextLine());
    writer.close();

    //Read
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("the-file-name.txt"));
    try {
        while (line != null) {
            usersName = line;
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } finally {
    br.close();
    }
```

Add your logic for determining if there is sth in that file yourself please.

Comment: Roberto, I am not sure why I need this in an extra file?  I am relatively new at programming and I haven't seen this before.

Comment: What is it exactly what you want to do. Just explain slowly please.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think you might be getting confused about the lifetimes of variables. In java, variables like `String username;` exist only in their own scope.

If you define a variable inside a method, it will be forgotten about when the program exists the method.

If you define it as a field inside a class (what you were doing), it will only exist as long as the instance of the class exists. As soon as the program forgets about the instance of the class, it also forgets about anything attached to that instance, including its variables.

Once the program shuts down, the computer naturally forgets about all objects that the program held, and so the `username` ceases to exist.

If you want the program to remember some value across shutdowns, you have to store that value in a file or a database or whatever. I recommend using a file, to make a database for this would be overkill squared. I will refer you to Roberto's answer from an hour ago for more info on how to achieve this exacly.